# Trying to compile a blank window with GTK3

Tags: c++, linux, gtk3

I want to learn how to code GUI programs in Linux, so I chose GTK3, but I'm running into some issues compiling the code for a simple blank window in GTK3. I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE, and this is my code. I'm almost certain it's correct because I copy-and-pasted it from a well known GTK tutorial site. Anyway, here's the code I have:

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;


  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);


  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);


  gtk_main();


  return 0;
}
```

The code can't compile, and Code::Blocks states: "fatal error: gdk/gdk.h: No such file or directory"

I don't know why it says this, because I can look in my usr/include folder and I see the gdk folder as well as gdk.h within it. Before I tried to compile the code I installed GTK 3.0+ via the following console command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

What am I doing wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: I can confirm the code looks good. I am not sure thought if the include shouldn't be rather `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`. Can you show your include paths? Did you try to compile on the commandline using `gcc` and `pkg-config`?

Answer (score 0):

just use #include .
if u build with pkg-config and gcc, it should looks like gcc -Wall filename filename.c -o `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`